# How can I reset Anaconda spyder setting

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

How can I reset my python editor, spyder? I touched setting by mistake, So I want to reset my spyder.
I delete it and download again, but this problem didn't solve.
So I want to know how reset spyder setting
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZMkg.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Tools > Reset Spyder to factory defaults
[image: Tools > Reset Spyder to factory defaults]

Then click yes
[image: Then click yes]

Spyder will restart, then you should see that the settings have reverted

Comment: Thank you for your advise but my screen is too big to click toolbar, So I have to reset from outside, how can i do it?

Comment: @전영주 can you provide a screenshot? I don't quite understand what you mean

Comment: I uploaded the screenshot